# Define a pointer with an arbitrary span

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

If I have a large array where the data streams are interleaved in some complex fashion, can I define a pointer p such that p + 1 is some arbitrary offset b bytes.

For example lets say I have 1,000,000 ints, 4 bytes each.

```
int* p_int = my_int_array;
```

This gives me *(p_int+1) == my_int_array[1] (moves 4 bytes)

I am looking for something like

```
something_here(b)* big_span_p_int = my_int_array;
```

which would make *(big_span_p_int + 1) == my_int_array[b] (moves 4*b or b bytes, whichever is possible or easier)

Is this possible? easy?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

b is compile time variable.

Comment: Since `*p_int = my_int_array[0]`, then
`*(p_int+1) == my_int_array[2]`  should actually be `*(p_int+1) == my_int_array[1]`. It's still a good question, I upvoted :)

Comment: Your question is unclear because if you have an `int*` it already moves `4` bytes every time you add `1` to it (if `int` is 4 bytes wide). So what do you want that is different from what currently happens?

Comment: So, why do you want it to have a built-in "span"? If you want to move an `int *p` pointer by `b * sizeof(int)` bytes, you can simply do `p += b`. Creating a pointer with a built-in span that jumps the same distance when incremented by 1 is just syntactic sugar. Granted, it can be useful in generic code... But what exactly are you doing that prevents you from just using `p += b`?

Comment: @AnT I assume the answer to that is generic code, perhaps involving the complex interleaving mentioned in the first sentence. You don’t need a page on why to answer “Make a class with binary `operator+`, unary `operator*`, `operator->`, etc.”. This is in fact what I intend to do when I’m less busy, if nobody beats me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using some of your code. There is no need to declare an additional pointer/array. Applying **pointer arithmetic** on `p_int` is enough to  traverse and reach the number value you are seeking.

**Let's look at this example:**

```
    int main() {
        int my_int_array[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
        int* p_int = my_int_array;
        int b = 2;
        std::cout << *(p_int + b) << std::endl; // Output is 3, because  *p_int == my_int_array[0], so my_int_array[2] will give you the third index of the array.
    }
```

**Graphically represented:**

```
Memory Address | Stored Value (values or memory addresses)
----------------------------------------------
0              |     .....
1              |     .....
2              |     .....
3              |     .....
4              |     .....
5              |     .....
6              |     .....
7              |     .....
8              |     .....
.              |     .....
.              |     .....
.              |     .....
n-1            |     .....
```

Imagine the memory as being a very big array in which you can access positions by its memory address (in this case we've simplified the addresses to natural numbers. In reality they're hexadecimal values). "n" is the total amount (or size) of the memory. Since Memory counts and starts in 0, size is equivalent to n-1.

**Using the example above:**

**1. When you invoke:**

```
int my_int_array[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

The Operating System and the C++ compiler allocates the integer array memory statically for you, but we can think that our memory has been changed. E.g. Memory address 2 (decided by the compiler) now has our first value of `my_int_array`.

```
Memory Address | Name - Stored Value (values or memory addresses)
-----------------------------------------------------
0              |     .....
1              |     .....
2              |     my_int_array[0] = 1
3              |     my_int_array[1] = 2
4              |     my_int_array[2] = 3
5              |     my_int_array[3] = 4
6              |     my_int_array[4] = 5
7              |     .....
8              |     .....
.              |     .....
.              |     .....
.              |     .....
n-1            |     .....
```

---

**2. Now if we say:**

```
int* p_int = my_int_array;
```

The memory changes again. E.g. Memory address 8 (decided by the compiler) now has a int pointer called *p_int.

```
Memory Address | Name - Stored Value (values or memory addresses)
-----------------------------------------------------
0              |     .....
1              |     .....
2              |     my_int_array[0] = 1
3              |     my_int_array[1] = 2
4              |     my_int_array[2] = 3
5              |     my_int_array[3] = 4
6              |     my_int_array[4] = 5
7              |     .....
8              |     p_int = 2 (which means it points to memory address 2, which has the value of my_int_array[0] = 1)
.              |     .....
.              |     .....
.              |     .....
n-1            |     .....
```

---

**3. If in your program you now say:**

```
    p_int += 2; // You increase the value by 2 (or 8 bytes), it now points elsewhere, 2 index values ahead in the array.

    Memory Address | Name - Stored Value (values or memory addresses)
    -----------------------------------------------------
    0              |     .....
    1              |     .....
    2              |     my_int_array[0] = 1
    3              |     my_int_array[1] = 2
    4              |     my_int_array[2] = 3
    5              |     my_int_array[3] = 4
    6              |     my_int_array[4] = 5
    7              |     .....
    8              |     p_int = 4 (which means it points to memory address 4, which has the value of my_int_array[2] = 3)
    .              |     .....
    .              |     .....
    .              |     .....
    n-1            |     .....
```

When doing **memory allocation** and **pointer arithmetic** in a simple case like this, you don't have to worry about the **size in bytes** of an int (4 bytes). The pointers here are already bound to a type (in this case **int**) when you declared them, so just by increasing their value by integer values, `p_int + 1`, this will **make point p_int point to the next 4 bytes or int value**. Just by adding the values to the pointers you will get the next **integer**.

Answer (score 0):

If `b` is a constant expression (a compile-time constant), then pointer declared as

```
int (*big_span_p_int)[b]
```

will move by `b * sizeof(int)` bytes every time you increment it.

In C you can use a run-time value in place of `b`, but since your question is tagged [C++], this is not applicable.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I am looking for a span based on compile time variable, not constant.  I updated the question to clarify.